# should i set up email adress with host or registrar?

Tags: web-hosting, domains, email

I own a website with godaddy.com and have an email address set up with them that came for free when i bought the domain name. they charge for any additional email addresses and they also charge to forward emails as well. I have my my web hosting separately from them with another company. My question is, will i be able to set up emails with my web hosting without going through go daddy or am i forced to buy them with godaddy.com? any help would be very much appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford it and have a use for it, Google Apps Business is a great option. You'd need to add a few custom MX records, and that's it. (Can be done in GoDaddy). For a more personal touch, you could run your own mail server, and that would handle any amount of email addresses and forwards for free. We currently use GA for our public mail, and then internal and system-status emails (cronjobs, hardware failures) get sent via a mail server on our network.

However, for a single user, or less than ten email addresses, sticking with GoDaddy isn't a bad option. You'll have to balance your needs with your budget, and then make the decision from there.

Comment: well im looking for free alternatives that wont require me to switch my current hosting service.

Answer (score 1):

As ionFish mentioned, Google Mail is a definite way to go. I have several domains and use their mail services. Each domain has less than 10 users. I enjoy the integration with other Google services and the android phone/tablets. I'm unsure if you will get the same compatibility with GoDaddy's Mail Services.

Comment: but is google mail free, and how do i set it up with my domain name?

Comment: You register your domain name with GoDaddy. You can then change the MX Records to GMail's. Go to www.google.com/a to start a new account. They will require you to verify ownership of the domain using one of a few different methods. Once you go through the different steps, it will show you the MX records than needs to be changed. Depending on your luck, integration with Google and Godaddy is much better now and it may do it for you. Your username will be your actual full email address when logging into gmail.

Answer (score 1):

You can get free email hosting at zoho.com they give 3 free accounts and you have complete control over them unlike at GoDaddy who charges for common features.

Comment: i have a web host for my website, how do i link the email host to my website then?

Comment: That's an entirely different question. The best answer is to read their wiki on setting up your email accounts http://zohomail.wiki.zoho.com/